# Params not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, network-programming, vagrant

I'm doing an API application, where I have a POST route:

```
{
    "user_id":"1"
}
```

this route calls the method of my controller:

```
def shouts
  puts(params)
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  render json: {status: 0, message: "sucess", data: @user.yells}
end
```

what happens is that when I test the postman on my machine runs smoothly. And it is possible to accompany the `puts` the terminal:

```
Started POST "/api/shouts" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-01-27 16:11:16 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Api::YellsController#shouts as */*
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "yell"=>{"user_id"=>"1"}}
{"user_id"=>"1", "controller"=>"api/yells", "action"=>"shouts", "yell"=>{"user_id"=>"1"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Yell Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "yells".* FROM "yells" WHERE "yells"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Category Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_yells" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_yells"."category_id" WHERE "categories_yells"."yell_id" = $1  [["yell_id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK
```

however when testo on another machine within the same network, the stop comes with nothing, or even this coming:

```
Started POST "/api/shouts" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-01-27 16:09:04 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Api::YellsController#shouts as */*
{"controller"=>"api/yells", "action"=>"shouts"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 500
```

Anyone know what can this happening? How fix? It's something I have to set in my vagrant machine? Or on the server? Or ruby on rails?

**UPDATE**

I discovered that I was wrong in my call on the postman was forgetting to put on a Content-Type Header = aplicatio / json.

Is there any way of pre configure this in ruby on rails? Put that all calls will have the same header.

Comment: Well, it is an application error, I guess this is because there is no params and it should backtrace something like undefined method yells for NilClass. Can you give us the routing and the backtrace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this in your application controller:

```
before_filter :set_format

def set_format
  request.format = 'json' # Or whatever you want
end
```

Or in your routes.rb

```
resources :shouts, defaults: { format: 'json' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails restricts verbose log output for remote machines in terminal.

That's why the error:

```
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
```

But actually the `params` is okay. You can use it normally in controller.

Anyway, if you want same verbose log for another machine, you can whitelist the IP in your `development.rb` file.

```
config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '10.0.2.2'
```

Comment: Why **Completed 500** then ?

Comment: `params[:user_id]` works? I guess it should be `params['user_id']`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it may be limited to local host.  Try running your rails server like this to allow external connections.

```
rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```